# Начал писать ис и наткнулся на вот такой код сущности бд и не могу понять зачем здесь нужен override?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
class Sotr
    {
        public int sotrID { get; set; }
        public string FIO { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FruitStorage> fruit_Storages { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FIO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: как правило такое вставляют для отладки.

Comment: В отладчике для экземляра данного класса вы увидите значение свойства FIO, вместо "MyProject.Models.Sotr", то же самое если вы попытаетесь вывести этот объект в логи или консоль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда нужно вернуть значение одного свойства как в данном примере, то не стоит использовать overrtide ToString(), я же приведу пример где возвращаемое значение будет чуть сложнее чем одно свойство.
У каждого объекта .net есть метод ToString(), который возвращает строковое значение, если мы напишем следующий код:

## Sotr

```
    public class Sotr
    {
        public int sotrID { get; set; }
        public string FIO { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FruitStorage> fruit_Storages { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var fruits = string.Join(", ", fruit_Storages); //читать ниже

            return $"{FIO}\n" +
                $"Фрукты: {fruits}";
        }
    }
```

## FruitStorage

```
    public class FruitStorage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }
```

**Метод ToString()** тут переопределен ключевым словом override и возвращено нам будет то что описано в теле метода, в данном случае это название фрукта.

## Console.WriteLine() - Смотрим конечный результат

```
sotr = new Sotr()
{
    sotrID = 1,
    FIO = "Фамилия Имя Отчество",
    fruit_Storages = new List<FruitStorage>()
    {
        new FruitStorage(){Id = 1, Title = "Яблоко"},
        new FruitStorage(){Id = 2, Title = "Груша"}
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(sotr.ToString());
```

**Результат:**

*Фамилия Имя Отчество*

*Фрукты: Яблоко, Груша*

## Разбор

Разберем метод *ToString()* в объекте *Sotr*

**Метод string.Join()** - Сцепляет элементы указанного массива или элементы коллекции, помещая между ними заданный разделитель.

```
var fruits = string.Join(", ", fruit_Storages);
```

В результате мы получили строковое значение следующего вида: Яблоко, Груша.

```
return $"{FIO}\n" +
    $"Фрукты: {fruits}";
```

И возвращаем **{FIO}** - ФИО **\n** - перенос строки и вставляем в конце **Фрукты: {fruits}**

Answer (score 2):

ToString() всегда надо оверрайдить, чтобы вызов данного метода заходил в конечный объект, пример:

```
class A
{
    public override string ToString() => "A";
}
class B : A
{
    public override string ToString() => "B";
}
class C : A
{
    public string ToString() => "C"; //<--
}
A b = new B();
A c = new C(); //<--
WriteLine(b); //Output B
WriteLine(c); //Output A //<--
```

Разница в override и дело не в сущности БД